# How to write a Query to find out if the item has been purchased in the last year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table ,where I have fields like Item and Purchase date. There are multiple entries of item purchased on different dates. I want to only select those items that are NOT purchased in the last 12 months. 
For eg. as shown below, I just need the value of 'IPad' as it has never been purchased in last 12 months.

```
**Item*** **Purchase Date**
 Laptop      22-Mar-19
 Laptop      17-Nov-16
 Laptop      26-Jan-15
 Laptop      27-Nov-19
 Ipad        26-Jan-17
 Ipad        5-Sep-16
 Ipad        12-Jan-15
```

How can I achieve it  using an Oracle sql query ?

Comment: I'd consider NOT EXISTS, or GROUP BY/HAVING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct item
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where item = t.item and purchase_date > add_months(sysdate, -12)
)
```

or:

```
select item
from tablename
group by item
having max(purchase_date) < add_months(sysdate, -12)
```

Comment: Hi.. Actually all 3 of them works..I wanted to select all the answers as correct answers , but it seems I can just select 1 as correct answer.

Comment: Since I am going ahead with your way of not exists clause, I will then pick yours as the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select item
from mytable
group by item
having max(case when purchase_date > add_months(sysdate, -12) then 1 end) is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GROUP BY` as following:

```
SELECT ITEM 
FROM
    (SELECT ITEM, 
            MAX(Purchase_Date) AS MX_Purchase_Date 
       FROM YOUR_TABLE
       GROUP BY ITEM)
WHERE MX_Purchase_Date < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12)
```

Another option is to use `NOT EXISTS` as following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ITEM
FROM YOUR_TABLE TOUT
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_TABLE TIN
    WHERE TOUT.Purchase_Date > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12) 
    AND TOUT.ITEM = TIN.ITEM)
AND TIN.Purchase_Date < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12) ;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would have a table `items` with one row per item.

Then the best approach is:

```
select i.*
from items i
where not exists (select 1
                  from purchases p
                  where p.item = i.item and
                        p.purchase_date > add_months(sysdate, -12)
                 );
```